# How do I draw graphics on top a ChartPanel?

Tags: java, graphics, jfreechart, mouselistener

I have a ChartPanel object displaying some information, but I would like to be able to use a MouseListener interface to draw on top of it. I'd imagine I would just have to call some sort of "repaint()" method at the end of the interface methods and perform some override, but after spending considerable time researching I haven't a clue how to go about doing this. Is this even possible? Any insight or advice?

Comment: You extend from `ChartPane` and overide it's `paintComponent` method.  You could use an `Overlayout` manager, you could use `JXLayer`/`JLayer` depending on what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a class that implements the [Overlay](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/panel/Overlay.html) interface and then add it to the ChartPanel using the [addOverlay(Overlay)](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel.html#addOverlay%28org.jfree.chart.panel.Overlay%29) method.  Everything that the overlay draws will be drawn after (so on top of) the chart.